# Sort MySQL table records

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables "states" and "countries"

### states

state_id
country_id
state_name
state_code

### countries

country_id
country_name
country_code

How do I display states list according to the alphabetical order of country name.
I am using PHP and MySQL

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM states LEFT JOIN countries ON states.country_id = country.country_id ORDER BY country_name
```

You'll possibly want to create an index on `country_name` for faster results.

That answer is the straight up SQL. If you want to run it via PHP, I'd suggest looking into PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 0):

are you famimliar with ORDER BY? use `ORDER BY COUNTRY_NAME` in your SQL query